# Run share/scripts/javascript command line macro

Tags: javascript, macros, openoffice.org

I need to run javascript macro from command line. My .js script is located at

> open_office_location/share/Scripts/javascript/MultiplyCSV/multiplycsv.js

I found this:

> soffice.exe -headless "D:\test1.ODS" "macro://test1/Standard.Module1.Main"

How can I identify module name of my script?
I tried:

> "macro://full path to .js file"
>
> "macro://MultiplyCSV.multiplycsv.js"
>
> "macro://MultiplyCSV/multiplycsv.js"

and more others.. 
I can't find solution.

Sorry for my bad english.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to assign it to the "Open Document" event.  This will run a macro whenever the document is opened.  To do this, go to `Tools -> Customized -> Events`.  More information is at: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Getting_Started/How_to_run_a_macro

If you need more flexibility, you can set up a Basic function to call the Javascript code.  Then use the `macro://` syntax.  To do this, first add this Basic function to Module1, adapted from the [authoritative Andrew Pitonyak document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php):

```
Sub CallMultiplyCSV
    Dim oDisp
    Dim sMacroURL As String
    Dim sMacroName As String
    Dim sMacroLocation As String
    Dim oFrame
    oDisp = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
    REM To figure out the URL, add a button and then set the button
    REM to call a macro.
    sMacroName = "vnd.sun.star.script:MultiplyCSV.multiplycsv.js"
    sMacroLocation = "?language=JavaScript&location=share"
    sMacroURL = sMacroName & sMacroLocation
    REM I want to call a macro contained in ThisComponent, so I
    REM must use the frame from the document containing the macro
    REM as the dispatch recipient.
    oFrame = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
    oDisp.executeDispatch(oFrame, sMacroURL, "", 0, Array())
    'oDisp.executeDispatch(StarDesktop, sMacroURL, "", 0, Array())
End Sub
```

Then call this Basic function:

```
soffice.exe -headless "D:\test1.ODS" "macro://test1/Standard.Module1.CallMultiplyCSV"
```

For details on `sMacroName` and `sMacroLocation`, see: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Scripting/Scripting_Framework_URI_Specification